# Animated movie where young boy is transported to another world and travels with a burly warrior and a owl like wise man

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I literally don't remember anything about this except a specific scene where the wise companion keeps correctly guessing how many fingers the protagonist has behind his back.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sounds like the 1992 cartoon series *Mighty Max*, an action adventure cartoon starring a boy named Max that had a magical cap that let him open portals to other locations. He was accompanied by a giant musclebound warrior named Norman, and a Lumerian "fowl"  named Virgil, who looked much like an anthropomorphic owl or a chicken as they joked in the show.

In the season one episode, "Bring Me the Head of Mighty  Max", [according to Wikiquotes](https://en.m.wikiquote.org/wiki/Mighty_Max#):

> Max: Look, I already told you I am not going back down there! Besides,
>   how do you know that's my destiny?
>
> Virgil: Because I know almost everything.
>
> Max: Oh yeah? Okay...who was the king of England in 1298?
>
> Virgil: Edward the Second.
>
> Max: Well, how many people are living right now in...Calcutta?
>
> Virgil: Sixty seven million, nine hundred and eighty two thousand,
>   seven hundred and thirty two...thirty three, sorry.
>
> Max: Okay, well, uh... [He puts a hand behind his back.] How many
>   fingers am I holding up behind my back?
>
> Virgil: Three.
>
> [Max does a surprise take as he realizes that Virgil is correct.]
>
> Max: Whoa...

Answer (score 5):

Your question suggests Mighty Max, except that was a series, not a movie. The burly warrior (named Norman, believe it or not) was the titular Max's protector while the owl-man Virgil advised Max when necessary (which was a lot). Max didn't so much travel to another world as go to different parts of earth though portals opened by his magic baseball cap (one *did* lead to outer space).